# Plugin Upgrade Strategy

Tags: plugin-development, upgrade

Reading [register_activation_hook()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook#Changelog) told me that in wordpress 3.1, this will only work for every plugin activation, not plugin upgrade.

What I want to know is, what's the best plugin upgrade strategy?

My though is:

1. on action 'admin_init' check for '{plugin_name}_version' option

   1. if '{plugin_name}_version' doesn't exist, let's assume it's from previous version (because at that version, we don't have '{plugin_name}_version' option, yet. Go to process 2.
   2. if '{plugin_name}_version' option exists and doesn't match with '{plugin_name}_version' set in script, go to process 2.
   3. if '{plugin_name}_version' option match with '{plugin_name}_version' set in script, exit process.
2. launch our plugin upgrade function with '{plugin_name}_version' value as parameter
3. do whatever needed for this upgrade process
4. after upgrade process finished, set '{plugin_name}_version' option to '{plugin_name}_version' from script.

Any comment for this process?

Answer (score 3):

This was recently discussed at length on the wp-hackers list. Here's the thread:

- [**Will Activation Hook Be Executed During Plugin Upgradation?**](http://groups.google.com/group/wp-hackers/browse_frm/thread/fa6eb2c49baa674a/03abe9d4174267f4?tvc=1#03abe9d4174267f4)

Quoting [Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto) from the list:

> The simplest method that would work
>   everywhere would be simply to  store
>   the version number of the plugin
>   somewhere (like in your options  entry
>   in the database), then compare the
>   stored version with your  known
>   current and hardcoded version. When
>   you detect the difference,  then that
>   means an upgrade has taken place, and
>   you can act  accordingly.  Another way
>   is simply to make the plugin detect
>   outdated options or  older schemas and
>   upgrade them on-the-fly. This is
>   probably the most  reliable, but it
>   does depend on what exactly you're
>   upgrading. You  can't necessarily make
>   this "generic".